# Why doesn't the If statement get triggered?

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote some code to detect a skip in a continuous sequence of letters. I've narrowed it down to the if statement not activating.

The there should be an inconsistancy between my list of the alphabet and the sequence when it skips a letter. However it doesn't appear and just bulldozes straight to the end return statement. I've bolded the if statements that aren't working

```
public class Sequence {
  public static char findMissingLetter(char[] array) {
    String ualphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String lalphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (String.valueOf(array[1]).compareTo("_") < 0) {
      int Start = ualphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(array[0]));
      int End = ualphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(array[array.length-1]));
      for (int i = 0; i < (End-Start); i++){
        if (!(String.valueOf(array[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(ualphabet.charAt(Start+i)))==0)){
          return((ualphabet.charAt(Start+i)));
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      int Start = lalphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(array[0]));
      int End = lalphabet.indexOf(String.valueOf(array[array.length-1]));
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
        if (!(String.valueOf(array[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(lalphabet.charAt(Start+i)))==0)){
          return((lalphabet.charAt(Start+i)));
        }
      }
    }
    return('a');
  }
}
```

Comment: `if` statements like `if (!(String.valueOf(array[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(ualphabet.charAt(Start+i)))==0))`?  It's not any surprise you can't understand what that's doing given all the operations you've needlessly crammed into one line.  That style of writing code has led you to write code you are unable to understand.  Stop doing that.  Spread it out over multiple lines using temporary variables you can examine in a debugger.  **And never forget where writing code with too much crammed into one line led you**.

Comment: By the way, italics and bold don't work within code blocks.

Comment: Off-topic: Did you know `char` in Java is an integer primitive type? You can do arithmetic with `char`, just as you can with `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`. You could have, for example, `char current = Character.toLowerCase(array[i]); int difference = current - previous; if (difference > 1) { ...`, where `previous` is also a `char`.

Comment: There are 3 ifs in the snippet. To which one are you referring?

Comment: Try running the code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `String ualphabet =`  line. Then, run the code one-step-at-a-time, while monitoring variables. When it pauses at the `if` statement that isn't working, note carefully the values of the variables present in the `if`. Predict whether the `if` statement will be `true` or `false`. Use pen and paper if it will help.  If you still can't figure it out, try breaking the expression in the `if` statement into small pieces, using temporary variables.

Comment: `if (!(String.valueOf(array[i]).compareTo(String.valueOf(ualphabet.charAt(Start+i)))==0))` is a very verbose and difficult-to-maintain way of writing `if (array[i] != ualphabet.charAt(Start+i))`.  You don’t have to convert values to strings just to compare them, especially when they’re numeric values.